# Vlad the Deployer - Usage Patterns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, vlad-deployer

I'm starting to use vlad for new deployments and am wondering what's the best way to set it up so I can use the same tasks for my local development and remote production servers?

I thought about defining everything as remote tasks then having dev/prod methods which set the domain variable, then I can just call `rake dev/prod vlad:do_something`, but this just feels totally wrong.

Many of my tasks are useful to run on my local server and on my production server and I want to avoid repeating myself by having one 'task' for local and one 'remote_task' for remote. e.g.

```
def do_something
  run "echo something"
end

task :do_something_dev
  do_something
end

remote_task do_something_prod
  do_something
end
```

Am I missing something or are these really the only options for using the same rake tasks on both the local and remote machine?

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
[:development, :test, :production].each do |environment|
  namespace environment do
    task :do_something do
      echo "do something on #{environment}"
    end
  end
end
```

This will give you:

- `rake vlad:development:do_something`
- `rake vlad:test:do_something`
- `rake vlad:production:do_something`

With just one method it is probably less verbose to do it your way. But as soon as you have 2 or three methods, the overhead can be neglected.